# Attach SQL to button

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I want to get data from a MySQL Database;

**EDIT**:

I want to be able to modify a query in order to obtain different rows corresponding to a specific date, using a datapicker.

I need to generate a report (an Excel file) from a query, make it user-friendly, using HTML and PHP but I don't know how to do that.

EDIT: Sorry, I am going to edit this question:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";  
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
?>
<html>  
 <head>  
  <title>Attempt to get data</title>  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 </head>  
 <body>  
  <div class="container">  
   <br />  
   <br />  
   <br />  
   <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h2 align="center">Export MySQL data to Excel in PHP</h2><br /> 
    <table class="table table-bordered">
     <tr>  
                         <th>Name</th>  
                         <th>Address</th>  
                         <th>City</th>  
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
     <?php
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
     {  
        echo '  
       <tr>  
         <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["Address"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>  
         <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
       </tr>  
        ';  
     }
     ?>
    </table>
    <br />
    <form method="post" action="export.php">
     <input type="submit" name="export" class="btn btn-success" value="Export" />
    </form>
   </div>  
  </div>  
 </body>  
</html>
```

And

```
<?php  
//export.php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "testing");
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST["export"]))
{
 $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";
 $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  $output .= '
   <table class="table" bordered="1">  
                    <tr>  
                         <th>Name</th>  
                         <th>Address</th>  
                         <th>City</th>  
       <th>Postal Code</th>
       <th>Country</th>
                    </tr>
  ';
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '
    <tr>  
                         <td>'.$row["CustomerName"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["Address"].'</td>  
                         <td>'.$row["City"].'</td>  
       <td>'.$row["PostalCode"].'</td>  
       <td>'.$row["Country"].'</td>
                    </tr>
   ';
  }
  $output .= '</table>';
  header('Content-Type: application/xls');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls');
  echo $output;
 }
}
?>
```

Take a look at this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer";
```

there is a column called `CREATED_AT` in my table and I want the user to be able to dynamically change the value of that in  the page.

I mean:

SELECT * FROM tbl_customer
where CREATED_AT >= (here, the user should be able to adjust this field in the view of the page, otherwise he Will get several rows from different dates). I don't know how to do that :(

Also, I would like to display a load bar when clicking on export to Excel.

[image]

Comment: The "I want" and "I need" make this too broad/unclear. Please post code you tried that may have failed you.

Comment: _"is that even possible?"_ Yes, it is.

Comment: Oh, sorry guys @FunkFortyNiner; I am gonna edit my question. Im sorry :(

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner take a look, buddy

Im sorry, my previous question was bad

Comment: @digijay could you please take a look at this?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @programming_always :) Now, is this what you thought would be working code to accomplish what it is you do want to do? If it doesn't work because something might be wrong somewhere or there's a syntax error, I suggest you enable error reporting and to catch and display them, including checking for errors on the query.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry, the first time the question was bad, really bad. Dude, i ve been trying to pass a date and use it in the where clause (using a prepared statement), then put a date picker in the main page but i am super lost. Nothing is working :(. Could you please  help me with that? I swear, im lost :/. My code is working just fine, i was able to obtain the Excel file but i dont know how to do the other part :(

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner How am i suppose to modify the query and use the datapicker? Can you give me a hand? Also, i know how to make a progress bar but i was not able to adapt it into the code because i dont know how to do the datapicker part

Comment: Datapickers are JS right? If so, I am not your guy for this. Plus, it's nearing supper time here, so I have to tend to things :)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, it is. Oh,damn it :/. I dont know how to edit the query because otherwise the user will get several rows.. i  want the user to be able to choose for a specific date (thats related to php)

Comment: Firstly add an input field into your "export" form where the user can type a date. If you're targeting HTML5 you can simply it as `type="date"` and you get a graphical date picker for free in most browsers, no JavaScript required. Then you need some code on the server side to read the date value from the $_POST array and add it as a parameter to the query

Comment: P.s. The loading bar is probably impossible because you need to do a postback in order to initiate the file download. Hopefully your query isn't so slow that it matters!

Comment: @ADyson take a look at this (i've created a new question - more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159668/trying-to-pass-a-date-and-use-it-in-the-where-clause-date-picker-progress-bar ). Could you please take a look at this?

Comment: You shouldn't really duplicate your questions, but I'll take a look. Maybe delete this one if you've got another one which is better

Comment: @ADyson Oh, i'm sorry, guys :(. Okay, please. Thanks, buddy :)